# Query doesn't excecute for a select count of a particular column value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
select 
    count(*) as allCount, 
    sum(t.status='Approved') as approvedCount, 
    sum(t.status='Overdue') as overdueCount, 
    sum(t.status='Rejected') as rejectedCount, 
    sum(t.status='Awaiting Approval') as awaitingApprovalCount,
    sum(t.status='Not Submitted') as notSubmittedCount
from 
    timesheet as t 
where 
    t.empl_id = 2;
```

In this query it shows a run time exception as

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.querySyntax.Exception:expecting CLOSE ,found "=" nearline 1,sum(t.status="Approved")

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there try use sum (case when

```
select count(*) as allCount, 
sum(case when t.status='Approved' then 1 else 0 end) as approvedCount, 
sum(case when t.status='Overdue'  then 1 else 0 end) as overdueCount, 
sum(case when t.status='Rejected' then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedCount, 
sum(case when t.status='Awaiting Approval' then 1 else 0 end) as awaitingApprovalCount,
sum(case when t.status='Not Submitted' then 1 else 0 end) as notSubmittedCount
from timesheet as t where t.empl_id=2;
```